# could not execute 'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)

Tags: tag

I am using Ubuntu xenial (16.04.1)
Problem is: kernels can not be updated or I cannot upgrade to 16.10, because after 'aptitude upgrade' or 'dorelease-upgrade -d' I get: 'could not execute  'apt-key' to verify signature (is gnupg installed?)'
gnupg is already the newest version (1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1) on my system

how to fix?
recommendations from googling did not help me.